# Combine WindowsAuthentication with rules stored in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application that uses WindowsAuhhentication to authenticate the user. Now I need to add a security layer to this application and would like to base this on the standard MVC security model and use the AuthorizeAttribute. This relies on User.IsInRole, but currently this will return the groups that the user belongs to. I do not want to have to store roles as groups in the AD, instead I would like to just have the roles for each user stored in my DB.

So the question is, how do I override the IsInRole method in the WindowsPrincipal, or can I create a CustomPricipal that does what I want?

I have found lots of information on similar topics but most of them seem to reference MVC4 and from what I can gather the entire security model has changed between MVC4 and MVC5. So what is the best way of doing that now?

All help and pointers much appreciated.

Cheers Mike

P.S. And if anyone has any idea how to best incorporate EF, IOC and caching into this then that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what I have done. I would really like peoples feedback as to best practice and improvements I could make.

1. I created a new Principal derived from WindowsPrincipal and with an overridden IsInRole Method.

   ```
   public class QSDPrincipal : WindowsPrincipal
   {
       private readonly IUserService userService;

       public QSDPrincipal(WindowsIdentity ntIdentity,
           IUserService userService) :
           base(ntIdentity)
       {
           this.userService = userService;
       }

       public override bool IsInRole(string role)
       {
           return userService.CurrentUserIsInRole(role);
       }
   }
   ```
2. This uses DI to populate the userService object that lives in my BL layer. So I had to configure the container to build this properly.

   ```
   container.RegisterType<WindowsIdentity>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
       new InjectionFactory(x => (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity));

   container.RegisterType<IPrincipal, QSDPrincipal>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
   ```
3. The I use the DependencyResolved to create my new Principal in the PostAuthenticateRequest event.

   ```
   protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var newUser = (IPrincipal)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IPrincipal));

       HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
   }
   ```
4. Then in the UserService itself I implement a method and implement some simple caching so it only makes one DB query per request.

   ```
   public bool CurrentUserIsInRole(string role)
   {
       return CurrentUserRoles.Contains(role);
   }

   private IEnumerable<string> currentUserRoles;

   public IEnumerable<string> CurrentUserRoles
   {
       get
       {
           if (currentUserRoles == null)
           {
                    var user = GetCurrentUser();

               currentUserRoles = new List<string>
               {
                   user.Role.Name
               };
           }

           return currentUserRoles;
       }
   }
   ```

And that is it and it all seems to work.

Thoughts and improvements much appreciated.

Cheers Mike

Answer (score 0):

I have found MVC5 Asp.Identity to be really developer friendly compared to the old membership provider... which might be the reason there is a lack of documentation at this time. It is actually intuitive.

If your authentication rules reside in a database EntityFramework will convert stored procedures into Complex Types. After you do that you could create an 'AuthenticationService' service layer and use DI to inject the complex types into Asp.Identity as needed.

To customize Asp.Net Identity all you have to do is add properties to IdentityModels.cs and **AccountViewModels.cs**, by default Asp.Identity uses the **ApplicationDbContext** which you have to do absolutely nothing to configure.

In addition, you can access the users information in a similar manner to **User.IsInRole**.

Comment: Thanks for your response but, if I read you correctly, you have presumed that I want to use Forms Authentication, which I don't. The application uses Windows Authentication and needs to continue to use Windows Authentication.